# How to SET category/series name in PowerPoint charts?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm writing a macro to set categories/series names. New labels are taken from some dictionaries. My first step however was to **get** those names from each chart. So, in order to get it, I used the code below:

```
'works fine
'x - any integer
'whole sentence
Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(x).Shapes(x).Chart.ChartGroups(x).CategoryCollection(x).Name

'with variables
Dim objChart As Chart
Dim objChartGroups As ChartGroups
Dim objChartGroup As ChartGroup
Dim objCategoriesColl As CategoryCollection
Dim objCategory As ChartCategory
Dim strCategory As String

Set objChart = ActivePresentation.Slides(x).Shapes(x).Chart
Set objChartGroups = objChart.ChartGroups(x)
Set objChartGroup = objChartGroups.Item(x)
Set objCategoriesColl = objChartGroup.CategoryCollection
Set objCategory = objCategoriesColl(x)
strCategory = objCategory.Name
```

I checked this property (`Name`) many times on Microsoft Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/powerpoint.chartcategory.name) and it is stated that it is a **read/write** property. However, when I try to set a new name (in the code below) I receive an error. Is it possible there's a mistake in Docs?

```
Public Sub EnterNewChartCats( _
  lngCategoriesCount As Long, _
  objCategoriesColl As CategoryCollection, _
  dctDT As Dictionary, _
  dctConsts As Dictionary, _
  dctRegexes As Dictionary, _
  dctUniques As Dictionary)

  'lngCategoriesCount - number of categories in a chart
  'objCategoriesColl - CategoryCollection object (a list of categories)
  'dctDT - a dictionary for names where there's no need to change the label
  'dctConsts - a dictionary for non-unique names which appear many times in a presentation
  'dctRegexes - a dictionary for names which can be replaced using regular expressions
  'dctUniques - a dictionary for names taken from an Excel file (already done)
  
  'booleans for check if a name appears in a dictionary
  Dim blnInDT As Boolean
  Dim blnInConsts As Boolean
  Dim blnInRegexes As Boolean
  Dim blnInUniques As Boolean
  Dim blnAdd As Boolean

  'creating standard variables
  Dim objCategory As ChartCategory
  Dim i As Long
  Dim strCategory As String
  Dim strUCaseToCheck As String
  
  For i = 1 To lngCategoriesCount
  
    Set objCategory = objCategoriesColl(i)
  
    strCategory = Trim(objCategory.Name)
    
    'trimmed and upper-case category string to compare with dictionary keys
    strUCaseToCheck = UCase(strCategory) 
    
    'checking if a category appears in a dictionary
    blnInDT = blnInDct(dctDT, strUCaseToCheck)
    blnInConsts = blnInDct(dctConsts, strUCaseToCheck)
    blnInRegexes = blnAnyValueLikeDctRegex(strUCaseToCheck, dctRegexes)
    blnInUniques = blnInDct(dctUniques, strUCaseToCheck)
    
    'checking if a category meets a condition - at least 1 occurrence in any dictionary
    blnAdd = blnAnyValue(True, blnInConsts, blnInRegexes, blnInUniques)

    'blnAlphabeticChars - a function to check if a category has any letters because
    'there's no need to change such labels as '2021' etc.
    If Not blnInDT And blnAdd And blnAlphabeticChars(strCategory) Then

      'ERROR (objCategory.Name): Can't assign to read-only property
      If blnInConsts Then
        objCategory.Name = dctConsts(strUCaseToCheck)
      ElseIf blnInRegexes Then
        objCategory.Name = dctRegexes(strUCaseToCheck)
      ElseIf blnInUniques Then
        objCategory.Name = dctUniques(strUCaseToCheck)
      End If
    End If
  
  Next i
  
  Set objCategory = Nothing

End Sub
```

I've found a workaround (`SeriesCollection(x).Values` or `.XValues`) but it's not convenient to use. **So, my question is: does exist any way to use `Name` to set new labels? If no - do you know other workarounds?**

EDIT: I've finally managed to change labels via `objChart.ChartData.Workbook` but it's very slow and, more importantly, a workbook has to be activated (opened) in order to refresh categories/series names. That influenced performance and time of execution greatly so I'm still looking for any other way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Your first listing is trying to set the name of **.CategoryCollection(1)**. But the help page that you linked to is about **.ChartCategory**.

In any case, here's how to set the category names:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryNames = Array("Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4")
```

Comment: I edited my first listing to explain what's the link between `.CategoryCollection(x)` and `.ChartCategory`. What's the possible problem with `objCategory.Name = "Example"`?

There are 4 sources of **visible** labels in a chart: categories, series, legend, data labels. If some axis is not present in a chart it may happen that categories/series values are shown in legend or data labels. After all, labels are always taken from categories or series. That's the reason why I need to change cats/ser explicitly in a collection. Changing labels on axes would cause error if cats/ser axis didn't exist.

Comment: The line I posted sets the names for the Category collection whether the axis is visible or not. Microsoft documentation is riddled with errors, so it could be that property is read-only. VBA documentation is hosting on GitHub. Here's the page where you can suggest fixing this mistake: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/VBA-Docs/blob/master/api/PowerPoint.chartcategory.name.md

Comment: I tried your solution (`Axes(enum).CategoryNames`) on two situations I encounter the most. My results: 1) Series axis doesn't exist and labels are in a legend - Err(5): Invalid procedure call or argument; 2) Categories axis doesn't exist and labels are in data labels: Method 'CategoryNames' of object 'Axis' failed. I'll submit an issue on GitHub anyway.